# List pairs of bacteria affected by same antibiotics

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the last task in my first sql query assignment, and I find it considerably more difficult than the other tasks. **I have three tables**:

- Bacteria(bid,name)   - contains id and names of bacteria
- Antibiotic(aid,name) - contain id and name of antibiotics
- Effect(aid,bid)      - contains id of an antibiotic that affects an bacteria (bacteria id used)

**The task asks** to give the pairs of bacteria which are affected by the same antibiotics (if an antibiotic affects bacteria A, it should also affect bacteria B - same goes for the opposite).

This is what **I am thinking**:

```
SELECT b1.*,b2.*
FROM Bacteria b1, Bacteria b2
WHERE b1.bid, b2.bid IN (SELECT e1.bid, e2.bid
                         FROM Effect e1, Effect e2
                         WHERE e1.aid = e2.aid)
```

I know the syntax is wrong and maybe even my approach.

**What is the best way for me to approach this task?**

Thank you

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty simple.  It is a self-join.

First, though, I want to admonish you for using commas in the `FROM` clause.  If you are learning SQL, you should learn it correctly, and learn to use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

So, the idea is:

```
SELECT e1.bid, e2.bid
FROM Effect e1 JOIN
     Effect e2
     ON e1.aid = e2.eid AND
        e1.bid < e2.bid;  -- no need to include the same pair twice
```

This returns the bacteria ids.  I'll let you work on getting the actual names.

Comment: I imagine they need a relational division query here. That the set of all antibiotics should be the same, not just at least one in common.

Comment: Martin is correct on that all antibiotics should be the same. However, thanks for pointing me in the direction of using self-join, a quick read gives me the intuition that this is what the task wants me to learn.

Comment: @Hako . . . Your question (as rendered in English) definitely does *not* suggest that all antibiotics needs to be the same.  Further, I would be surprised to see such a question on a first assignment.  In English, plurals are definitely ambiguous in this context.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. Looking at Martin's solution it seems that the task would be too difficult if they needed exactly the same effects. I chose to build onto your code, and I have posted my solution for you guys to see.

Answer (score 1):

You need a relational division query here.

For the following data

```
CREATE TABLE Effect
(
aid INT,
bid INT
);

INSERT INTO Effect
VALUES (20, 1),
       (21, 1),
       (20, 2),
       (21, 2),
       (21, 3);
```

One way of extracting the needed info would be

```
SELECT eaids,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bid
                      ORDER BY bid SEPARATOR ',') as bids
FROM 
(
SELECT bid,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT aid
                      ORDER BY aid SEPARATOR ',') as eaids
       FROM Effect
       GROUP BY bid
) T
GROUP BY eaids
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Which returns

```
    eaids   bids
    20,21   1,2
```

Showing that bacteria with ids 1 and 2 are both affected by the same set of antibiotics (20 and 21)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TLF1703)